# why does the player with custom controls keep working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a player application that has a problem with unloading itself when the link changes (react routing). On the first load www.host/video everything is fine, but when exiting /video, the player events (play/pause on space) player continue to work on all pages. When I returning to the www.host/video page, the player loads the styles from the player.scss but does not respond to clicks, and the first player also continues to respond to events. The player is not displayed in the dom but the jsxPlayer.js continues to work.

**How do I unmount a component when pathname is not equal to "/video"?**

jsxPlayer.js

```
import React from 'react';

import "./../player/player.scss"
class Player extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

componentDidMount() {
    if (window.location.pathname == "/video") {
        import ("./../player/player.js")
    }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    if (window.location.pathname != "/video") { 
    // what i must to do here?
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <video id="Player" src="./video.mp4" ></video>
            <div className="timeLines"></div>
            <div className="playerController">

                <button id="play">Play</button>

                <input id ="volume" type="range" ></input>
            </div>
        </div>    
    )
} } export default Player;
```

video.js

```
import Player from './components/player.js';


class Video extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
       super(props)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="dokoaPlayer">
            <Player />
        </div>
       )
    }
} export default Video
```

player.js

```
document.querySelector('#play').onclick = play;
document.querySelector('#volume').oninput = videoVolume;

let Player = document.querySelector('#Player')

function play() {
    if (!(Player.currentTime > 0 && !Player.paused && !Player.ended)) {
        Player.play();
} else {
    Player.pause();
} }
```

App.js

```
import AppRoutes from './AppRoutes';
const App = () => {
    return (
            <Routes>
                {AppRoutes.map((route, index) => {
                    const { element, ...rest } = route;
                    return <Route key={index} {...rest} element=  {element} />;
                })}
            </Routes>
    );
}
```

AppRoutes.js

```
   const AppRoutes = [

    {
      index: true,
      element: <Home />
      },
      {
       path: '/home',
       element: <Home />
      },
      {
       path: '/video',
       element: <Video />
      },
     ];
     export default AppRoutes;
```

index.js

```
root.render(
<div>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <App />
        <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

);

Comment: Wasn't this exact question asked a day or two ago? The component unmounts when it's no longer rendered by a matching route. Please share all relevant code you are working with and have an issue using as part of your [mcve]. If possible could you also create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese If the question was asked 2 days ago, you can find it, link it and flag this one as a duplicate

Comment: @deaponn I am aware, thanks. I am pretty certain it was a question asked by this same OP, which it seems they've since deleted, so there's nothing to flag as a duplicate.

Comment: Why are you mixing function components with class components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically I'm a bit lost in your code:

1. You mix functional and class components
2. You have a file `player.js`, which isn't a react component at all, and you import it in `video.js`, but somehow your app is behaving like you imported `jsxPlayer.js`

Besides that, the issue lies in your `player.js` file, because:

1. You reference your DOM by `document.querySelector`, this should be done by adding `useRef` to your components
2. You are not cleaning up your `.onclick` and `.oninput` events

To fix your issue, you should clean up your event listeners:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    // the below line could also be a mistake, 
    // because a component could be unmount before the URL changes, 
    // so this would not fire because window.location.pathname is still "/video"
    // keep in mind that componentDidMount fires when your component renders to the screen
    // and componentWillUnmount fires right before it disappears from the screen
    // so when the URL changes to "/video", react-router renders your components
    // thus there is no need to check for the window.location.pathname
    // if (window.location.pathname != "/video") {
    // what i must to do here?
    document.querySelector('#play').onclick = null;
    document.querySelector('#volume').oninput = null;
    // }
}
```

I think it should work right away but it is not clean way to do it